# UIKit & SpriteKit Problems: Timer and Games

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

I am working on a game where all of my code for the game is in the GameScene.swift file (new levels, game over , scoring system , etc...).

I wanted to add a functionality of a timer to make the game more interesting and asked a question here which was answered.

To my question, is there a way I can create a UILabel in GameScene for the timer instead of putting the timer in the UIViewController file? It would be difficult to reference everything from GameScene in UIViewConroller .. any suggestions?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You better create a custom class for the label and put the timer logic inside it

```
class customLb:UILabel
{ 
   var timer:Timer!

   func start()
   { 
       self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.2  ,
                                             target: self,
                                             selector: #selector(self.doIt), userInfo: nil,repeats: true)

   }

    func doIt()
    {
       self.text = //change here
    }
    func stop()
    {
       if(self.timer != nil)
       {            
          self.timer.invalidate()

          self.timer = nil
       }
     }
 }
```

Comment: That would require a new storyboard for this, correct?

Comment: set the class name of the label in storyboard to the name of that custom label

Comment: Okay. So instead of doing the label first then dragging it into the code you're saying create it in the code then go the main storyboard and basically edit the name of the class to the one I create to host the timer logic.